# Toolbar does not appear at UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, toolbar

I'm testing [Xamarin.Forms Book samples Chapter 13 ToolbarDemo](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Chapter13/ToolbarDemo).

The toolbar appears in Android phone but it does not appear in UWP (Windows 10, not mobile).

I have not modified any code.

**Expected**
[image: Expected display]

**Actual**
[image: Actual display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Xamarin.Forms used in the sample project contains a bug that causes title bar and toolbar not to display in UWP - see the [issue tracked](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3297) on Xamarin.Forms repository on GitHub. This has been since fixed in the stable branch and you can just update the Xamarin.Forms version used in your solution from NuGet.

Right-click your solution node in the **Solution Explorer**, choose **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...** and from there click on **Updates** and feel free to update all listed packages to latest stable version (especially Xamarin.Forms, that is :-) ).

[image: Working sample]

You can also control the positioning of the toolbar by using `this.On<Windows>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom)`.

Comment: If it solved the question, please mark the answer as solution, so that it is closed :-)